# Multiple fixed icons on bottom of page but only one showing

Tags: html, css

I figured out how to fix the icons to the bottom of the page but now for some reason only one will show.  I've tried to put them each in their own div but still not working?

HTML:

```
<div style="position: relative">
       <img src ="./images/tw.jpg">
        <img src ="./images/ig.jpg">
        <img src ="./images/fb.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
       height: 40px;
       width: 40px;
       position: fixed; 
       bottom: 0; 
       text-align: center;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <img src ="./images/tw.jpg">
    <img src ="./images/ig.jpg">
    <img src ="./images/fb.jpg">
</div>
<style>
.container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.container img {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Worked,  thanks.  I'll give you the answer when it allows me

Answer (score 1):

add `position:fixed` in div

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove 'position:fixed' from css or replace it with 'position:relative'

Comment: that worked but now the icons are not fixed to the bottom of the page?